# Firebase setValue on offline

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I would to save user data into firebase when he signup, But there is a problem which is if he created Auth account and then lost connection before saving his info, That's mean he will get Email\Password without any profile info.

So the question is how to setValue again if he lost connection or exit the app?

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: self.emailTxt.text!, password: self.passTxt.text!, completion: {
        (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            if let isError = error?.localizedDescription
            {
                print(isError)
            } else {
                print("Error: 33")
            }
        }
        else if user != nil
        {
            // Email and password created
            let userInfo: [String : Any] = ["timestamp": FIRServerValue.timestamp(),
                                            "uid" : user!.uid,
                                            "email" : self.emailTxt.text!,
              //  This info must be send again if its failed.
                                        ]
              self.ref.child("users").child("profile").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(userInfo) {
                (error, ref) in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error set profile info")
                    // What should i do if its failed? 
                } else {
                    print("done creating user's profile")
                }
        }
    }
    }// Completion end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Use disk persistence, which means the data will be written when the user comes back online. This is what Pipiks' answer explains.
2. Don't rely on the client-side to create the registration information, but use a Cloud Function.

For the second option you're using [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to write [JavaScript code that is executed on Google's servers when the user account is created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation). See this [example of sending a welcome email](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users) (that you'll have to modify to write to the data instead).

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the **Disk Persistence** :

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

**Firebase apps automatically handle temporary network interruptions. Cached data is available while offline and Firebase resends any writes when network connectivity is restored.**

Here the [Firebase Offline Capabilities documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

Comment: I've wrote that in appDelegate, But when i click on Signup then fast turn off the internet, Only Authentication "Email\password" Created, nothing wrote on database also if i connect to internet again! This is error i've got "Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."

Comment: I think you need to use Firebase Cloud Function to do that properly. (See Frank van Puffelen's answer)